# Is it possible to hide react native WebView scrollbars and keep scrolling enabled?

Tags: css, react-native, webview, scrollbar

I have managed to hide page scrollbars by using `:-webkit-scrollbar` and `display:none`. And it looks as expected in the browser but when I run that page via react native app with WebView then i still see scrollbars on Apple devices. Is it possible to hide them?